# Search a string and list all sentences matching that string

Tags: string, scala, full-text-search

I am trying to code in Scala for the following use case:

Search a string in a text file and list only the sentences that has a match for this string.

I tried using the following:

```
val fileContents = Source.fromFile("/Users/sc/Documents/Scala_Code/input.txt").getLines.mkString

val sentence = fileContents.filter(line => fileContents.contains("string to search"))
```

This lists the entire text file even if there is one match.  I need just the sentences that has a match.

Appreciate if someone can provide some inputs.

Comment: Is your text in english or another langage?

Comment: Can sentences extend on multiple lines?

Comment: Hi,Yes, the sentences can extend multiple lines.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's kind of hard to be sure to describe a sentence in regex. Nevertheless, here's my suggestion:

for all sentences (in case you want to pattern match on them):

```
"""\A?\b((?!\?+"?|!+"?|\.+)(.|\n))+(\Z|\?+"?|!+"?|\.+)""".r.findAllIn(fileContents.mkString) //.toSeq
```

For a specific string (for example `you`):

```
"""\A?\b((?!\?+"?|!+"?|\.+)(.|\n))+(\Z|\?+"?|!+"?|\.+)""".r.findAllIn(fileContents.mkString).toIterator.withFilter(_.contains("you")) //.toSeq
```

`toSeq` (or `toList`) is useful for checking on small amount of data...

You can test it here: https://scalafiddle.io/sf/0znMzyi/8

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @DW_BD, I think I can make a better code out of this info.

Comment: I have updated it. Unfortunately, some things bother me:

Comment: - Does your point _a._ take into account the first sequence of words? Because it may not follow punctuation, as the first sentence, this is a special case.
- You describe a sentence as something which start as the first non-whitespace character after, among other things, a newline, but at the same time, a sentence can be splitted up by newlines. So when a sentence starts at the beginning of a line, isn't it because there was a punctuation finishing the line before?
- your error is a bit confusing because the underlying data should wrap `String`s. I've added a `toIterator` to assure this

Comment: Hi Benjamin, I still get the same error, probably some package/class missing? Please see the error message below:   "error: value contains is not a member of Char".   println((pattern_stack1 findAllIn source).mkString("\n---->>>>").toIterator.withFilter(_.contains("you"))) ~~~~~. The error is pointing to the "c" in the _.contains.

Comment: I found the problem, you don't want to call `.mkString("\n---->>>>")` on your results at this step because it changes a `Seq[String]` into a `String`, which is considered as a `Seq[Char]` and explain the error. It's better to do `val myResults = (pattern_stack1 findAllIn source).withFilter(_.contains("you"))` and then a routine like`myResults.map(_ + "\n---->>>>").foreach(print)`.

Comment: actually `withFilter` is something which permits to kinda filter sentence lazily, which you may want if you have a huge file. It's its use which make the code looking like this.

Comment: Thank you for your help!